# Jsoup multiple forms with controls with same name

Tags: forms, jsoup

All this html on same page:

```
<form name="name1" ....>
<input name="tName"type="text">
<input value="Search" type="submit">
</form>

<form name="name2"....> 
<input name="tName" type="text">
<input value="Search" type="submit">
</form>


 doc = Jsoup.connect("addr")
            .data("tName", "foo")
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .post();
```

Now, how do I know which form I submited ? Where to specify to which of 2  forms inputed data belogs to, in jsoup code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="name1" ....>
<input name="tName"type="text">
<input value="Search" type="submit">
<input name="formNumber" value="form1" type="hidden">
</form>

<form name="name2"....> 
<input name="tName" type="text">
<input value="Search" type="submit">
<input name="formNumber" value="form2" type="hidden">
</form>


 doc = Jsoup.connect("addr")
            .data("tName", "foo")
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .post();
```

If you can't get the name of the form itself, you'll be able to get the values of the hidden inputs.